# JavaScript comma seperated values in function body

Tags: javascript, syntax

I recently read some source code that contained a function similar to the one below:

```
function foo(someArray) {
  const arrayPrime = someArray.map(x => x * 2,);
  return arrayPrime;
}
```

To my surprise, the code above is valid - no syntax errors.

Playing with this code more, we can add any number of values separated by commas without generating a syntax error:

```
function foo(someArray) {
  const arrayPrime = someArray.map(x => x * 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
  return arrayPrime;
}
```

Invoking both versions of `foo` with `foo([11,2,3])` yields `22,4,6`.

Can someone explain why this is legal?

Comment: The second version is returning [22,4,6]. Testing with `node v14.17.3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are additional arguments to the `map()` method.

`map()` takes 1 optional argument, the value to be passed as the `this` context to the callback function. Since arrow functions can't have their `this` value altered, so it's ignored in this case.

The remaining arguments are ignored completely. JavaScript doesn't report errors when a function is called with more arguments than it needs. (It also doesn't report errors for missing arguments, they're just set to `undefined`).